# gem to commit files into git from ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

Hey I am working on ruby on rails application where user can create set of instructions in the form of text. We have a requirement to save this text (dynamic) into git. Could someone suggest which is the best gem to achieve below:

1. I have to push text into git as a zip folder.
2. I need to pull latest text from git to the UI.
3. If any conflicts, need to handle error messages.
4. We need to show all the files available in git.

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the [git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) fulfills your needs. Keep in mind that the text and zip parts of your requirements has nothing to do with git so you should use other gems and/or standard library things to get your stuff into and out from zip files.

To find a gem for something you can go to [rubygems](http://rubygems.org) and type in what you need in the search field. The result shows number of downloads which may be an indication of where to look further.